# Django REST combining Meta. models

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models in model.py

```
class a(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  name=models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
class b(models.Model):
  id = models.ForeignKey(a, null=True, blank=True)
  age = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Id is Unique here.,
In my serializer form I need the  name and age in single API form.

```
class conform(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class  Meta:
        fields = ( 'name','age')
        model = a
```

is not adding the age field how to add the age field to conform.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reach "age" field from "a" model, you can do it through "related_name" attribute  model. In your case it can be like this:

```
class b(models.Model):     
    a = models.ForeignKey(a, unique=True, related_name="profile")
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

And then you can use it in serializer like this:

```
class conform(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class  Meta:
        fields = ( 'name','profile__age')
        model = a
```

Comment: still it says Field name `profile__age` is not valid for model `a`.